# InfluxDB 1.7.2 - Top X over time

Tags: influxdb

I’m new to InfluxDB. I’m using it to store ntopng timeseries data.

ntopng writes a measurement called `asn:traffic` that stores how many bytes were sent and received for an ASN.

```
> show tag keys from "asn:traffic"
name: asn:traffic
tagKey
------
asn
ifid
> show field keys from "asn:traffic"
name: asn:traffic
fieldKey   fieldType
--------   ---------
bytes_rcvd float
bytes_sent float
>
```

I can run a query to see the data rate in bps for a specific ASN:

```
> SELECT non_negative_derivative(mean("bytes_rcvd"), 1s) * 8 FROM "asn:traffic" WHERE "asn" = '2906' AND time >= now() - 12h GROUP BY time(30s) fill(none)
name: asn:traffic
time                non_negative_derivative
----                -----------------------
1550294640000000000 30383200
1550294700000000000 35639600
...
...
...
>
```

However, what I would like to do is create a query that I can use to return the top N ASNs by data rate and plot that on a Grafana graph. Sort of like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygv0j.png) example that is using ELK.

I've tried a few variants from posts here and elsewhere, but I haven't been able to get what I'm after.  For example, this query I think gets me closer to where I want to be, but there are no values in `asn`:

```
> select top(bps,asn,10) from (SELECT non_negative_derivative(mean(bytes_rcvd), 1s) * 8 as bps FROM "asn:traffic" WHERE time >= now() - 12h GROUP BY time(30s) fill(none))
name: asn:traffic
time                top                asn
----                ---                ---
1550299860000000000 853572800
1550301660000000000 1197327200
1550301720000000000 1666883866.6666667
1550310780000000000 674889600
1550329320000000000 20979431866.666668
1550332740000000000 707015600
1550335920000000000 2066646533.3333333
1550336820000000000 618554933.3333334
1550339280000000000 669084933.3333334
1550340300000000000 704147333.3333334
>
```

Thinking then that perhaps the sub query needs to select `asn` also, however that proceeds an error about mixing queries:

```
> select top(bps,asn,10) from (SELECT asn, non_negative_derivative(mean(bytes_rcvd), 1s) * 8 as bps FROM "asn:traffic" WHERE time >= now() - 12h GROUP BY time(30s) fill(none))
ERR: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported
>
```

Anyone have any thoughts on a solution?

**EDIT 1**

Per the suggestion by George Shuklin, modifying the query to include `asn` in `GROUP BY` displays ASN in the CLI output, but that [doesn't translate in Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8WnT.png).  I'm expecting a stacked graph with each layer of the stacked graph being one of the top 10 asn results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make ASN as tag, than you can use `group by time(30s), 'asn'`, and that tag will be available in the outer query.

Comment: `asn` already is a tag.  See OP (not sure how to properly quote it again in this comment).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: you hadn't tried 'asn' in `group by`. It's important.

Comment: Thanks.  That produced ASNs in the CLI output, but not in Grafana.  I've updated the OP to reflect that.